# LireSolr gives irrelevant results when queried and the result changes everytime for the same data set used

Tags: image, solr, cbir, lire

I have used the LireSolr and indexed around a 1000 images. Now i try to obtain a similar image from google, that is, if there is a black bag in the indexed data I get a black bag and I try to obtain histograms using above flow and for JCD, ColorLayout, PHOG and Edge Histogram but the results are irrelevant and the result changes everytime. On searching the same image as the indexed one also different result images as returned. Anyone encountered the same problem before?
Thanks for the help in advance..!!!

Comment: I have set ms = false and have also figured out that the randomrequestHandler is getting called. I guess I am making a mistake while querying LireSolr. Can someone give me an example in querying LireSolr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer, the query should be like this:-

**http://localhost:8983/solr/ImageMatch/select?q={!cache=false}*:*&sort=lirefunc(eh,"gICEkYGwg6CAgJOAg7GgwqCRsYDAgIGCgKCAg4GAkYOQwICEkYOTgA==")+asc**

Lirefunc is the function query and {!cache=false} disables the cache. This is necessary, otherwise even if we try to change the query feature in lirefunc the output results will be picked uo from the cache.